# How can I separate this Entity Framework model to prevent memory errors?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I am trying to work with a set of data from a legacy app and move it into a MSSQL database.  I created an app in C# with EF to manage the data.  The class structure as it is represents old C style arrays from the legacy app but with some class order.

These are the three main classes.  Other properties are involved but I have included only the main form and memory hog (AccountDetails) here.  When this structure is built out it has One Simulation - from 50 to 100 accounts and then each account has between 1000 or more Account detail objects.

If I add the whole structure at once - and do save changes I get a Memory error.  How can I add all my AccountDetail objects and keep it linked as one object structure?  Can I add them separately (I have all ID's and one to Many's setup properly though not all details are included here).

```
public class Simulation 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Account>     Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public List<AccountDetail>     Details { get; set; }
}
// trouble in here....
public class AccountDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Scenario { get; set; }
    public double M01 { get; set; }
     ..... class has 60 doubles for 5 years of payments ....
    public double M60 { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks,

K.

Comment: That M01-M60 is going to bite you or your colleagues one day.

Comment: This project was an experiemnt and not production code for future use.  The point of the M01 - M60 was to get a structure that represent 5 years we could store as a single table record.

It used indexes like this:

    RateEnvirSize = D_COS * D_BYTES * LINESIZE;

  Would you recommend a different way?

Comment: This project was an experiemnt and not production code for future use.   I understand its certainly not how we would want it in memory for programming, in that case I would use an List or similar type container. Sorry for two comments, edit took me longer then 5 minutes as I hit enter accidently and it posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you have all ids. Just do the following.

1. Create Simulation object and populate it only with non-navigation properties (so ints, doubles etc.) Save changes.
2. Create a list of Accounts and populate it only with non-navigation properties, but make sure that SimulationID (or the foreign key you are using to link Account to simulation is filled in). Save changes.
3. Create  list of AccountDetails, populate it only with non-navigation properites, but make sure that AccountID (or the foreign key you are using to link Account details to Account is filled in).

In entity framework, you don't need all the objects to be in memory. It's the foreign keys that matter. Now you can save the memory by saving only 10 accounts at a time if you want to. But to be honest, I haven't seen yet EF complaining about memory, so that raises question... have you set up everything correctly?

Comment: First, thanks for the answer.  I thought it might be something like that but still new to EF.  I believe I have setup everything correctly because if I make a test set with less accounts (but full structure) it works.  However a typical data set from the legacy app is 150 accounts, with 1290 detail lines per account with 60 doubles per detail line.  If my math is correct that turns out to be over 11,610,000 double values per simulation.